# Selenium handles '@' character very strangely

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium in python with **standard and with undetected_chrome** drivers in normal  and headless browser modes.
I've noticed some strange behaviors:

- normal **chrome driver** works fine with special inputs while sending keys into HTML input field with `send_keys()` function
- **undetected_chrome driver** does not handle the special inputs very well with `send_keys()` function

  - in **normal browser mode** if I send an email address into a HTML input field, like 'abc@xyz.com' the current content from the clipboard is pasted in place of '@' character

    - e.g.: if I have copied the string '123' for the last time, the entered email address will not be 'abc@xyz.com' but 'abc123xyz.com' which is obviously incorrect
    - that's why I'm using a workaround, that I import pyperclip and put '@' character to the clipboard before the `send_keys()` function runs, to replace the '@' character with '@' character correctly
  - in **headless browser mode** if I enter an email address into a HTML input field, like 'abc@xyz.com' my workaround doesn't matter any more, the '@' character will be stripped from the email, and the 'abcxyz.com' string will be put into the field

I think sending a '@' character shouldn't be that hard by default. Am I doing something wrong here?

**Questions**:

- Can anyone explain these strange behaviors?
- How could I send an email address correctly with headless browser mode? (I need to use **undetected_chrome** driver because of bots)

```py
from selenium import webdriver

self.chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
if self.headless:
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

prefs = {'download.default_directory' : os.path.realpath(self.download_dir_path)}
self.chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)
```

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# workaround for problem with pasting text from the clipboard into '@' symbol when using send_keys()
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('@')  #  <---- THIS IS THE WORKAROUND FOR THE PASTING PROBLEM

self.chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
if self.headless:
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    self.chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
self.driver = uc.Chrome(options=self.chrome_options)

params = {
    "behavior": "allow",
    "downloadPath": os.path.realpath(self.download_dir_path)
}
self.driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.setDownloadBehavior", params)
```

The versions I'm using `requirements.txt`:

```
selenium==4.3.0
undetected-chromedriver==3.1.5.post4
```

Comment: I am unable to replicate this. Could you test it using the input from another website just to rule out JS? If you still experience the same issue, please edit the post to include a complete [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Lucan Thanks for the idea! I've tested with google mail and the `@` symbol was sent correctly this time, so it's probably a site specific JS as you have mentioned. I'm not familiar how JS code is executed during the execution of `send_keys()` function. Could you please give an advice how could I workaround this problem? Thanks

Comment: @Lucan do you have any idea why the behavior of the **undetected_chrome** is modified by the JavaScript, but the behavior of the **regular chrome driver** isn't?

Comment: I am unsure why you see different behaviours based on the information provided. Is the website in question something you can share?

Comment: @Lucan I can share.. It's the https://www.tradingview.com

Comment: I assume you're trying to log in using email and password, so I have replicated the login process using the minimal steps I can. Unfortunately, I cannot reproduce your problem using UD or regular Chrome. So you must have something else in your code or receive different JS than me. Can you provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example); complete and minimal code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @Lucan I've created a sample code for you which is minimal, but broken: https://gist.github.com/elaspog/fc8b1592836e12c995ec90a91ff18577

Comment: @Lucan and this is how I see the in headless mode: https://freeimage.host/i/headless-mode-error.wveX2e and in normal mode (if I have copied something previously): https://freeimage.host/i/normal-mode-error.wvehYu

Comment: @Lucan I've put another reprex here: https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/728

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using custom configuration options, try a more basic variant first and see if works correctly. And then figure out which option combination is causing the issue.

An example (which does work correctly by the way)

```py
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = uc.Chrome()

driver.execute_script("""

    document.documentElement.innerHTML = `

        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>

            <meta charset="UTF-8">

            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

            <title>Document</title>

            <style>

                html, body, main {

                    height: 100%;

                }

                main {

                    display: flex;

                    justify-content: center;

                }

            </style>

        </head>

        <body>

            <main>

                <form>

                    <input type="text" name="text" />

                    <input type="email" name="email"/>

                    <input type="tel" name="tel"/>

                </form>

            </main>

        </body>

        </html>`
    """)



driver.find_element(By.NAME, "text").send_keys("info@example.com")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "email").send_keys("info@example.com")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "tel").send_keys("info@example.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

This complaint (entering "@" pastes clipboard contents) has come up here from time to time but I've never seen a definitive solution. I'd suspect a particular language version of Windows &/or keyboard driver.

Answer (score 0):

The windows language is the problem, more precisley the keyboard layout as it changes depending on language. Switch it to "ENG" and it should work fine. Keyboard layouts where letter Z is between "T" and "U" are not working with undetected driver. Keyboard layout that has Z next to "X" works fine.