# Problem when using @ in text or variables

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm using undetected chromedriver instead of a normal chromedriver
When @ is used in variable or text for .send_keys random stuff is put instead of @ :

```
username = 'test@gmail.com'
password = 'test'

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver.get('https://vb.rebelbetting.com/')
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(5)

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='usercom widget']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='close top-right']"))).click()

driver.find_element("id", "inputEmail").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element("id", "inputPassword").send_keys(password)
driver.find_element('id', 'inputPassword').send_keys("\n")
time.sleep(10)
```

Instead of  `test@gmail.com`  being filled into the login form
I get  `testundetected_chromedrivergmail.com`
When using normal chromedriver it works normally. It only happens when @ is used, other symbols work normally.

Wrong thing is being outputted

Comment: does `test\@gmail.com` work by any chance?

Comment: is this happening all the time? because I could not reproduce it!

Comment: This is what shows up if i use test\@gmail.com  -- > https://prnt.sc/pwujwcmmNMR7 @JonSG

Comment: Yes, its happening all the time. I tried reinstalling chromedriver aswell, but it didn't work

Comment: Just realised it's putting in whatever I copied last. So if a ctrl + c 'dada' it would replace @ with 'dada'

Comment: same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73018012/selenium-handles-character-very-strangely but the answer is not very helpfu

Comment: Yes! The windows language was the problem, more precisley the keyboard layout as it changes depending on language. I switched it to "ENG" and now it's working fine. Keyboard layouts where letter Z is between "T" and "U" are not working with undetected driver. Keyboard layout that has Z next to "X" works fine.

Comment: Thanks for linking that post I would have never found out what was the issue.